# Traeffic, Docker and Let's Encrypt

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

Final stage before my website can finally go live --> SSL.

I'm using a Jekyll site, with Traefic as a reverse proxy, Docker to prevent "it works on my machine" and Let's Encrypt for SSL. Looking at the docs this should be a walk in the park, but (as everything in software development) it is harder then it seems.

My current Traefic configuration:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
            entryPoint = "https"
            permanent = true
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
    endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    domain = "johanvergeer.com"
    watch = true
    exposedByDefault = true
    usebindportip = true
    swarmMode = true
[acme]
    email = "johanvergeer@gmail.com"
    storage = "acme.json"
    entryPoint = "https"
    acmeLogging = true
    caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    [[acme.domains]]
    main = "johanvergeer.com"
    [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
    provider = "digitalocean"
```

And the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  site:
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    image: registry.gitlab.com/johanvergeer/redgyro/site:latest
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.site.port=4000
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:johanvergeer.com
        - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-net
        - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method=drr
    networks: 
      - traefik-net

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - $PWD/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.site.port=80
        - traefik.logLevel=DEBUG
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-net
        - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.method=drr
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - traefik-net

networks: 
  traefik-net:
    name: traefik-net
```

At this moment I don't even receive anything in the Traefic logs, while it is set on DEBUG.

The browser shows an error `Your connection is not private` and `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`httpChallenge` does not accept a `provider` param. You could try removing that.

If that doesn't work and you're running on DigitalOcean try doing a [`dnsChallenge`](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#dnschallenge) instead of an [`httpChallenge`](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#httpchallenge). To do so modify your `traefik.toml` from this:

```
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
provider = "digitalocean"
```

To this:

```
[acme.dnsChallenge]
provider = "digitalocean"
delayBeforeCheck = 0
```

And pass in the `DO_AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable as [specified here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#provider). If you anticipate adding subdomains later [DNS challenge with wildcard domains](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/#dns-challenge-with-wildcard-domains) is the way to go.

Also consider removing `caServer` from your config so you default to production in case you've hit the [Let's Encrypto Rate Limit](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) for staging.

You could also try asking for help on the [Let's Encrypt Community Support](https://community.letsencrypt.org/) forum if you haven't yet.